# Problems with a code that constrains the movement of the cursor to the horizontal direction

Tags: autohotkey

I'm using a code that constrains the movement of the cursor to the horizontal direction when it is activated, but I have experienced the following issue: when toggling on the script, the cursor gets displaced down from its original position, instead of remaining at the same height.

The code I'm using is this one:

```
!s:: ; Hotkey will toggle status
Confine := !Confine
MouseGetPos ,, SetY
Confine ? ClipCursor( 0 , SetY , A_ScreenWidth , SetY+1 ) : DllCall( "ClipCursor" )
Return

ClipCursor( x1=0 , y1=0 , x2=1 , y2=1 ) {
    VarSetCapacity( R , 16 , 0 )
    NumPut( x1 , &R + 0 )
    NumPut( y1 , &R +4 )
    NumPut( x2 , &R +8 )
    NumPut( y2 , &R +12 )
Return DllCall( "ClipCursor" , UInt , &R )
}
```

I need the cursor not to jump. How could this behavior be fixed?

---

This question is related to another one that I posted previously:

[How to toggle an AHK script on/off with a key?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56426124/8861410)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinate SetY has to be relative to the desktop (entire screen).

```
!s:: ; Hotkey will toggle status
    Confine := !Confine
    CoordMode, Mouse, Screen ; If this command is not used the coordinates are relative to the active window.
    MouseGetPos ,, SetY
    If (Confine)
        ClipCursor( Confine, 0, SetY, A_ScreenWidth+1, SetY+1 )
    else
        DllCall( "ClipCursor" )
Return

ClipCursor( Confine=True, x1=0 , y1=0 , x2=1 , y2=1 ) {
    VarSetCapacity( R , 16 , 0 )
    NumPut( x1 , &R + 0 )
    NumPut( y1 , &R +4 )
    NumPut( x2 , &R +8 )
    NumPut( y2 , &R +12 )
    Return DllCall( "ClipCursor" , UInt , &R )
}
```

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/CoordMode.htm